# Downgrading SQL Server Express 2008 to SQL Server Express 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I was using Visual Studio 2008 and a service based database. One day I installed Visual Studio C# Express 2010 and it automatically upgraded SQL Server to SQL Server 2008. I want to use Visual Studio 2008, but it does not support SQL Server 2008.
Please tell me how to downgrade SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2005, so that it will be usable with Visual Studio 2008...

Comment: This should probably be moved to Super User or Server Fault???

Comment: @dboar no, this is a Visual Studio (dev tools) question primarily. Not a great question but it is in the correct place.

Comment: What are sercer and "service based database"?

Answer (score 8):

Download [VS 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en). It adds support for SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean it doesn't support it?
SQL Server version has nothing to do with Visual Studio.
You can use SQL Server Express 2008 with VS 2008 just fine.

Anyway there's no downgrade path. You can have both of them side by side though.

Comment: Mladen, the RTM of VS 2008 does not support SQL Server 2008. The Server Explorer uses SMO 2005 and cannot connect to SQL 2008.

Comment: ahhhh, now i get what he meant. thanx.